# Get a text from a mysql table, edit it and print it with php

Tags: php, mysql, html

What i want to do is get the details of each product from my database, make it to have a certain number of character ex at least 200 length but i want to edit it so tha it doesn't show half words. Here is the code that i have assembled but with no luck.

```
<?php 
//Block to show the latest products
$dynamicList="";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 6");
$product_count=mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($product_count > 0){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        $id=$row["id"];
        $product_name=$row["product_name"];
        $price=$row["price"];
        $details[]=$row["details"];
        $details = substr($details, 0, 490);
        for($counter = strlen($details); $counter >= 0; $counter--){

            if($details[$counter] != " "){
                $details=substr($details, 0, ($counter -1));
            }else if($details[$counter] == " "){
                break;
            }

        }


        $date_added=strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
        $dynamicList .='<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
                <tr>
                  <td width="20%" height="121" valign="top">
                  <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">
                  <img src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="auto" style="border:#FFFFFF 1px solid" height="150" border="1"/></a></td>
                  <td width="80%" valign="top">
                  <p><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $product_name . '</a></p>
                  <p>' . $details . '</p>

                  <p>' . $price . '€</p>
                  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="cart.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="'.$id.'" />
                        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Προσθήκη στο Καλάθι" />
                  </form>

                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>';
    }

}else{

    $dynamicList="We have no products in our store yet";    

}

?>
```

Comment: i get the error substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\4friends\index.php on line 20

Comment: as the error says $details is an array.

Comment: i deleted the [] from the line  $details[]=$row["details"]; but now i get the following message 490 times .... -> Uninitialized string offset: 490 in C:\xampp\htdocs\4friends\index.php on line 23

Comment: see my answer below for a cleaner way to do the cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `$details` is an array and at that part you are not using an array index. If you are wanting to use a string your best bet is to rename one of them so that PHP doesn't confuse the two.

Answer (score 0):

from the manual page for wordwrap, this should do what you want.

```
function cutstr($str, $length, $ellipsis=''){
   $cut=(array)explode('\n\n',wordwrap($str),$length,'\n\n'));
   return $cut[0].((strlen($cut)<strlen($str))?$ellipsis:'');
}
```

add the function to the page and replace lines 14 to 24 with:

```
$details=cutstr($row["details"], '200', '...');
```